# Confused about the return value from fread

Tags: c++, fread

I am trying to read a file in using fread. I'm basing it off of the documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

I want to read in 4 slices at a time from a file.

Here's what I have:

```
int vol_buffer_size = SLICE_SIZE * 4;  //SLICE_SIZE = 759000  bytes
unsigned short vol_buffer[vol_buffer_size];

 for (int j = 0; j < num_slps; j++){                   
    nByteRead = fread(&vol_buffer, SLICE_SIZE, 4, volFile);
}
```

When I do that, nByteRead comes out to 4 bytes on the first read. When I do it like this:

```
nByteRead = fread(&vol_buffer, 4, SLICE_SIZE, volFile);
```

nByteRead comes out to 759000 bytes, or one slice. But I want it to read 759000 * 4 bytes which equates to 4 slices. What am I doing wrong here? I'm confused because the documentation says the 2nd paramter is the size which I would think is SLICE_SIZE and the 3rd parameter is the count which I would think would be 4 in this case.

Comment: You don't say at which point `nByteRead` is 4. Are you only checking after the loop exits? In that case, nByteRead is the number of bytes read the last time `fread` was called. What is `num_slps` set to?

Comment: I'm breaking on the first fread. num_slps is 138 in this case

Comment: The docs you link to clearly say the return value is the number of elements read, not the number of bytes read. In your call, you request 4 elements of size 759000 each, and the return value confirms that 4 such elements were read.

Comment: Please read the documentation again.  The value returned is *not* the number of bytes read.

Comment: Ah alright I see. So the first scenario I was doing correctly. Didn't catch that thank you

Comment: `nByteRead ` is horridly named. It should be `nItemsRead` . [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) takes arguments of (1) the target buffer, (2) the size of *each* "item" in bytes, (3) the maximum *count* of items, and finally (4) the file pointer. If it returns `4` in the first example, it's because it read four items (each of which were `SLICE_SIZE` bytes in size), items successfully.

Comment: @WhozCraig nItemsRead is horribly named. it should be nSlicesRead.

Comment: @user2990406 try to add `long size=ftell (volFile);` after your `nByteRead = fread(&vol_buffer, SLICE_SIZE, 4, volFile);` you will see that **current value of the position indicator of the stream** is egal to 3036000 (759000  * 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fread` function is defined [as follows](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/):

```cpp
size_t fread (void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream);
```

where the `size` argument specifies the size (in bytes) of each element to read, and `count` specifies the (maximum) number of such elements to read. The return value is the **number of elements read successfully**.
So, in your first case:

```cpp
nByteRead = fread(&vol_buffer, SLICE_SIZE, 4, volFile);
```

the elements' size is given as `759000` and you are asking to read (up to) `4` such objects. The call succeeds and the function returns `4`.
In your second case:

```cpp
nByteRead = fread(&vol_buffer, 4, SLICE_SIZE, volFile);
```

you are asking to read `759000` elements, each of which is `4` bytes in size. Again, the call succeeds and returns how many elements were read.

In both cases, the **number of bytes** read is the same (`4 x 759000`) - but this **is not** what is returned by the `fread` function.